# How do i make <Input> checkbox element toggle on/off and change CSS classes/ids in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, input, checkbox, toggle

So i have been struggling with this for hours upon hours. I have been stuck with this for so long that i am slowly going insane. I cant recall how many times i rewrote this in different forms.

The toggle is suppose to activate "nightmode" by simply changing the classes. I have been able to chance classes/id with a simply button but couldnt make it toggle. I havent been able to do it with a "checkbox" type either.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="togglenightmode">`
```

Javascript

```
var bodyclass = document.getElementsByClassName("body");

var checkboxtoggle = document.getElementById("checkbox");
 
 function togglenightmode(){
     if (checkboxtoggle.checked === false){
         bodyclass.setAttribute("class", "body");
         console.log("Nightmode is OPEN");   
     } else 
     if (checkboxtoggle.checked === true){
         bodyclass.setAttribute("class", "body-nm");
         console.log("Nightmode is CLOSED");   
    } 
}
```

CSS

```
.body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.body-nm {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `body` the `<body>` element? Or is it actually a className on another element?

Comment: Also the oncick value needs to call the function `onclick="togglenightmode()"`. Note the `()`

Comment: yes the class of body element is called simply body aswell.

Comment: Try changing `getElementsByClassName('body')` to `querySelector('body.body')` or just `document.body`